# Exporting Mathml to Word Document using php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mathml

I'm creating a formula using MathML and it works when showing it on webpage. 
But what I need to do is creating a word document to be printed for paper test.

Is there any way to export MathML to word using php/laravel?